# java: need identity and equality at the same time

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a java project where I need both identity comparison (are the 2 references the same) and equality comparison (do both object contain the same data).
My solution is to not override equals/hashcode, and to add an isEqual method to my objects.
Is there a better pattern to deal with this situation?

EDIT:
Here is more information about this particular need.

By default we have:

- `equals` performing an identity check (==)
- `contains` being implemented in terms of `equals`, therefore using ==

But for my usage I would want:

- `equals` to perform an equality check (objects contain the same data)
- `contains` to remain implemented with ==

I can't have both at the same time, so one solution is to implement my
own equality check and have:

- `contains` staying the same, using ==
- implementing `isEqual` and use it instead of `equals`

another solution is to implement my own contains that uses ==:

- implementing `customContains` to use == and use it instead of `contains`
- Overriding `equals` to check whether objects contain the same data

Which is best? Is there another better way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by, are the two references the same?

Comment: overrite equals() and use both == and equals() ;) It really depends on the way you want to use it.

Comment: why don't you want to override them exactly?

Comment: I use these objects in lists, and often have to check whether a specific object (reference equality) is in a list with indexOf or contains. If I overwrote equals, I would have to implement my own version of indexOf and contains using ==

Comment: The alternative is writing your own `indexOf` and `contains` using `isEqual`, so just override `equals` and stick to convention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best pattern to do this is to follow the specification of the language.  Override equals and hashcode, and do not roll your own equality **UNLESS** and this is a big unless, no one outside of you will ever use this code **AND** it will never ever ever change.

If you want to wrap them in a function called `isEqual`, the hashcode and equals methods that is, this is another approach, but it still means you are overriding equals and hashcode, which you claim you do not want to do.

Essentially what you are doing is creating a very rigid and/or broken API, that will not see much usage as it will be difficult to utilize as your `isEqual` function could be quite non-deterministic.

Comment: so, it's better to overwrite equals/hashcode and implement my own contains/indexOf using == rather than keeping the original contains/indexOf and having a custom isEqual?

Comment: @Pierre I don't follow what you mean.  Index of has nothing to do with equals or hashCode.  Contains would not need to be overridden (this is what hashcode is for).  Can you clarify your question?

Comment: I edited the question with more information, thank you for your help so far.

Comment: @Pierre my statement still stands.  It doesn't make much sense imo to start arbitrarily changing definitions.

Answer (score 7):

Override the `equals()` method to determine if the objects contain the same data.

Use `==` to determine if they are the same object ie the same reference.